# clarification about Mobile Bar chart

Tags: xamarin.ios, teechart

i'm using TeeChartNETMonoTouchEvaluation_v2012_0_10_03
Evaluation version. it not support mobile bar chat (http://www.steema.com/uploads/gallery/BarForAndroidVert1.jpg) is it support in paid version. what are the additional features, styles supported in full version and there is any documation for the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in functionality between evaluation and registered versions of TeeChart. You need to add a rotation tool:

```
  tChart1.Tools.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.Rotate());
```

Alternatively, you can do that programmatically as well:

```
  Steema.TeeChart.Themes.BlackIsBackTheme myTheme = new Steema.TeeChart.Themes.BlackIsBackTheme(tChart1.Chart);
  myTheme.Apply();

  Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar bar1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar(tChart1.Chart);
  bar1.FillSampleValues();
  bar1.ColorEach = true;

  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = true;
  tChart1.Aspect.Orthogonal = false;
  tChart1.Aspect.Rotation = 320;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, exactly what i need is, need to show legend in bottom of the bar chart,
also in line chart need to show http://www.steema.com/uploads/gallery/PointnScatterLine.jpg like this. is there any setting for this?

Comment: Yes, for the legend you need to do this: tChart1.Legend.Alignment = Steema.TeeChart.LegendAlignments.Bottom;. And for the scatter plot: 
      Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line line1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line(tChart1.Chart);
      line1.Pointer.Visible = true;
      line1.Pointer.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.PointerStyles.Circle;